# How to select more rows based on column id of first select

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have 2 select statements. One returns 2 rows and the other must return more rows. I want to select all of the rows in one single query and not use a UNION because I will not be able to use the same column id with UNION.

My query is this

```
SELECT SUB.name FROM (SELECT U1.id ,U1.name, UOM.organization_id AS ORGID FROM #_users AS U1
                        JOIN #_user_organization_map AS UOM ON U1.id = UOM.user_id
                        JOIN #_rsdirectory_entries AS RSE ON UOM.organization_id = RSE.id
                        JOIN #_rsmembership_membership_subscribers AS RMS ON U1.id = RMS.user_id
                        WHERE RMS.membership_id = 66 AND UOM.organization_id = 301) AS SUB
JOIN #_users AS U ON SUB.id = U.id
JOIN #_user_organization_map AS UOM1 ON SUB.id = UOM1.user_id
JOIN #_rsdirectory_entries AS RSE1 ON UOM1.organization_id = RSE1.id
JOIN #_rsmembership_membership_subscribers AS RMS1 ON SUB.id = RMS1.user_id
WHERE UOM1.organization_id = SUB.ORGID;
```

What i'm trying to do is get all users belonging to a specific membership but not all users carry the membership_id value in their details in the database, only the CEO of the organization.

So, the nested SELECT should get the CEO's name to whom the subscription belongs (hence the membership_id) and then in the outer SELECT I want to get all of the employees under the same organization, by organization ID.

The result I get is the CEO's name twice but I should get the CEO's name and then all of the employees' names.

Comment: This isn't MySQL. MySQL doesn't use table names beginning with `#`.

Comment: @Barmar I replaced the tables' prefix with the # mate. Is that so important to you? If you cannot recognize that this is MySQL from the rest of the code then you cannot help me, sorry.

Comment: I thought it was SQL-Server because it uses `#name` as the way to name temporary tables.

Comment: The rest of the code is just generic SQL, I don't know how I would realize that it's MySQL rather than SQL-Server, Oracle, PostGreSQL, etc.

Comment: @Barmar well, since you mention oracle, to define an alias for a table you don't use AS like in MySQL. You simply define the alias immediately like SELECT column FROM table T1.

Comment: Please endeavor to progress all of your pages to a system recognized resolution.  If this is a query for Joomla, you might tag it as such.  If this is a Joomla question and you'd like to have the sql generated with Joomla's query building methods,  I recommend that you post on [joomla.se] to reach an informed audience.  So that volunteers can confidently answer your question, please post a testable db-fiddle.com demo.  Then volunteers will definitely be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery is only returning the CEO's information. The information about the employees is in the `U` table that you join with it.

But you can't join on `U.id = SUB.id`, because that just restricts `U` to the CEO's row. You want to get *all* the users in the same organization as the CEO.

I think this will do it. The last three joins get the organization ID of the CEO

```
SELECT U.name
FROM #_users AS U1
JOIN #_user_organization_map AS UOM1 ON1 U.id = UOM1.user_id
JOIN #_user_organization_map AS UOM ON UOM1.id = UOM.id
JOIN #_rsdirectory_entries AS RSE ON UOM.organization_id = RSE.id
JOIN #_rsmembership_membership_subscribers AS RMS ON U1.id = RMS.user_id
WHERE RMS.membership_id = 66 AND UOM.organization_id = 301
```

Comment: The result returned is the same.

Comment: Oh, that's because of `ON SUB.id = U.id`.

Comment: Give me a minute.

Comment: Exactly! This is what i'm trying to figure out. I cannot define the "general" U before SUB because CEO must be selected first and then retrieve the employees.

Comment: I just posted a query, but I don't think it's right. Could you add the table schemas to the question, and also some sample data and desired results?